# How to click on the download button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am trying to download an excel file using Selenium Python using the below code:

```
download=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1.0.1'>Download Orders]")
```

The element of the download button look like:
[image]

### The piece of code above isnt working. Can someone help?

Comment: "Download Orders" is text, not attribute value . Try to remove it: span[data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1.0.1']

Comment: @user2458552 locate button by css_selector and then use `download.click()`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS locator is wrong. Please try to click with below xpath.

```
//span[.='Download Orders']
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` with `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Download Orders']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`and `contains()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Download Orders')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Muzzamil that the CSS locator you have used seems wrong. @ is needed to select the attribute `data-reactid`.
You can try XPath:

```
//span[@data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1.0.1']
```

If you want to include also the text, try:

```
//span[@data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1.0.1'][contains(text(),'Download Orders')]
```